# rows as columns sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I have 2 tables like this

table 1

```
profile
--------
id
---
1 | XXX
2 | zzz
```

table 2

```
profile_details
-----------------
id |    K       |   V
---------------------------
1  | first_name | XXX
1  | last_name  | YYY
1  | gender     | female
2  | name       | zzzzz
2  | gender     | male
2  | phone      | 8999xxxx
2  | location   | india
2  | spoken_language | hindi
```

I use this query to fetch the rows as cols

```
select profiles.id,
max( decode( k, 'first_name', v, NULL )) first_name,
max(decode(k, 'last_name', v, null))as last_name ,
max( decode( k, 'gender', v, NULL)) gender
from profile_details , profiles
where 
profile_details.id = profiles.id 
and
profile_details.id=1
group by profiles.id
```

fetched me

```
id | first_name| last_name | gender
--------------------------------------------
1  |   XXX     |  YYY      | female
```

this works to fetch the rows as columns. but how can this query be changed to include the columns dynamically, as the K values can be anything possible.

ex, for id 2, it should be

```
id | name | gender | mobile   |   location  | spoken_language
------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | zzz  | male   | 8999xxxx |   india     | hindi
```

thanks
V

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "No".  SQL statement must explicitly list the columns being returned.  The extended answer is:  Do you know anything about dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to generate the string that you want to execute.

In Oracle, I would use a procedure that I could pass in the necessary `id` value and then return a `sys_refcursor`.

The procedure would be similar to the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot_profile(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_id in number)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select p.id ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct k from profile_details where id=p_id order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , max(case when pd.k = '''||x.k||''' then pd.v end) as "'||x.k||'"';

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from profile p 
                                                inner join profile_details pd
                                                  on P.ID = pd.id
                                                where PD.ID = '||p_id||'
                                                group by p.id';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then you return the results, I use the following in TOAD:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot_profile(:x, 1) -- pass in your id
print x
```

This will return the desired result that you provided.

Comment: How will be the performance of this query in case of huge data volume?

Comment: @user1353364 Any time you try to transform a huge data volume you could have performance issues.  That is partly why this type of data presentation should be done in the presentation layer of an application and not in SQL code.  Also you will want to be sure that you have appropriate indexes on your tables.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is an Entity-Attribute-Value schema, often used for providing flexibility in the schema.

The downside is that everything you do from now on will be unutterably painful and difficult, including this, for which there is no easy solution.

Here's a lesson on the the subject: https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/